# sed puzzle for a bash script modifying itself

Tags: bash, replace, sed

some time ago I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767816/create-polymorphic-bash-without-die-trying-sed-replacing). It was about a script which modifies itself and everything was working fine with the trick of putting a `[]` inside the sed regex in order to avoid modifying the sed line letting it find the correct one.

Ok, now is very similar but a little more complicated. In the other post, the line to search for was static. Now we have a couple of options for that line. So, sometimes the code is in this way (look at the line with the "set=x"):

```
#!/bin/bash
possible_locations=(
            "/somewhere/path/"
            "/another/different/path/"
            #Custom location (set=0)
            )
#Here goes my sed line
```

And other times the code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
possible_locations=(
            "/somewhere/path/"
            "/another/different/path/"
            "/other/one/path/" #Custom location (set=1)
            )
#Here goes my sed line
```

Keep and eye on tabs indentation at the beginning of the line.

Ok, what I want is to modify script itself (using `sed -i`) with a regex matching these two possibilities, without matching the sed line itself (like in the other post) and replacing this (set=x) line in both cases for:

```
            "/new/path/" #Custom location (set=1)
```

So I want to replace the line (keeping same tab indentation) which sometimes has only `#Custom location (set=0)` and sometimes have `"/other/one/path/" #Custom location (set=1)` for `"/new/path/" #Custom location (set=1)`

I tried different combinations capturing groups, etc... but can't make it work. I think I'm very close!!! Here is my non-working sed line:

`sed -i "s/^\(.*\)#[C]ustom location (set=[0-1])/\1\"\\/new\\/path\\/\" #Custom location (set=1)/" "/path/to/this/script.sh" 2> /dev/null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following which preserves spaces & tabs :

```
NEW_PATH=\"/new/path/\"

sed -ri "s_(\s+|\t+)([^ ]*)(\s*#Custom location \(set=)([0-9]+)(\))_\1$NEW_PATH \31\5_" test.conf
```

That uses the following groups :

- `(\s+|\t+)` matches any spaces or tabs
- `([^ ]*)` matches anything but space (for "path_string" if present)
- `(\s*#Custom location \(set=)` matches the comment until set=
- `([0-9]+)` matches the set value
- `(\))` matches the closing `)`

The replaced grouped are `\1$NEW_PATH \31\5` (1 is used for the `set` value)

Note that I added an additional space after `$NEW_PATH` variable for the case n°1 where there is no space present before the comment

Also note that I used `_` sed separator instead of `/` which would conflict with `$NEW_PATH`'s `/`

Comment: It was not exactly... some weird spaces appearing with your regex, but you pointed to me in the right way. I achieved it using: `sed -ri "s:(\s+|\t+)([\"0-9a-zA-Z/\-_ ]+)?\s?(#Custom location \(set=)([01])(\)):\1\"/new/path/\" \31\5:" "/path/to/this/script.sh" 2> /dev/null`. I changed the separator to `:` because `_` can be used as directory name. Same as spaces, so I tuned your regex a little bit but it was great. Thanks.